# Filtering through multiple dimesion Values

Tags: filter, x++, axapta

I have a dropdown(Dimesions) and a stringEdit LookUp(dimensionValue)  When I select a dimension suppose 'Branch' and a Value e.g. 'B001' I filter the result with the following query

`queryRun.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(LedgerTrans)).addange(fieldId2Ext(fieldNum(LedgerTrans, Dimensions), dimensions)).value(dimensionValue);`

where `dimensions` is enumValue, in the above query the enumValue for branch is `3` and `dimensionValue` is a string EDT.

Now I want to filter with multiple dimensionValues e.g. 'B001, B002, B002' etc. What modifications do I have to make in the query? Kindly assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code you should be able to simply enter "B001, B002, B002" (without the quotes) in your Value StringEdit control.

By the way I would advise you to modify your code as follows so that same ranges wouldn't be added over and over again:

```
SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(queryRun.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(LedgerTrans)), fieldId2Ext(fieldNum(LedgerTrans, Dimensions), dimensions)).value(dimensionValue);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i get an error `Argument '_queryBuildDataSource' is incompatible with the required type.` :(

Comment: Argument _queryBuildDataSource is `queryRun.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(LedgerTrans))`, right? I don't see why it would give such an error, but anyway even with your original code you should be able to filter by entering "B001, B002, B002" (without the quotes).

Comment: This should be more readable:
`QueryBuildDataSource qbds = queryRun.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(LedgerTrans));
FieldId fieldId = fieldId2Ext(fieldNum(LedgerTrans, Dimensions), dimensions);
;

SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(qbds, fieldId).value(dimensionValue);`